# How to enqueue style in WordPress plugin from theme files?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style

In my theme files I enqueue many css and js files. I want to enqueue some css files which are same as theme. So, how I can enqueue in plugin ?

Comment: Are you trying to enqueue your *theme's* CSS files in your plugin? Like, for example, your theme has a stylesheet at `wp-content/themes/my-theme/some-styles.css` and you want to be able to enqueue them from `wp-content/plugins/my-other-plugin/some-plugin-file.php`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to enqueue css file in plugin which already registered css inside theme files

Answer (score 0):

**IF** I'm understanding your question correctly, what you want to do is enqueue scripts and stylesheets using a plugin the same way you do with a theme... ...*if* that's the case then it's really not that different:

```
function yourplugin_enqueue_frontend() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'yourplugin-front', plugins_url( 'yourplugin-front.css', __DIR__ ), array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourplugin-front', plugins_url( 'yourplugin-front.js', __DIR__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourplugin_enqueue_frontend' );
```

I use `plugins_url( 'path-to-file.js', __DIR__ )` rather than `__FILE__` because I tend to organize my plugins directories with a lot of detail. So all of my functions are in separate files, in an `includes` directory, my javascript files are all in a `js` directory, CSS in a `css` directory, etc...  so it just makes it easier to be able to supply the proper path for each of the scripts and stylesheets I'm enqueuing.

The main difference is that with themes you use:

```
get_template_directory_uri() . 'theme-stylesheet.css'
```

But with a plugin you use:

```
plugins_url( 'theme-stylesheet.css', __DIR__ )
```

The rest is pretty much the exact same thing.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I really don't think you should do it this way, because then you're making a plugin dependent on a theme, which means if you change themes, you lose access to the file if the new theme doesn't have it or if the new theme has it in a different location...  for example, I put the file inside of a directory called `/css/`, but if you switch themes and the new theme has the same file but this time it's in `/assets/css/` then your enqueueing will break.

Regardless, because you asked for it, here it is...

```
function yourplugin_enqueue_frontend() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'yourplugin-front', plugins_url( 'yourplugin-front.css', __DIR__ ), array(), '1.0' );
        //THIS NEXT LINE ENQUEUES THE SCRIPT FROM THE THEME
        wp_enqueue_style( 'notagoodidea', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shouldnt-do-this.css', array(), '1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'yourplugin-front', plugins_url( 'yourplugin-front.js', __DIR__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourplugin_enqueue_frontend' );
```

I have tested this and it works...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="notagoodidea-css" href="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/thisisthetheme/css/shouldnt-do-this.css" media="all">
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I appreciate for your help.
But, I want to enqueue css/js from theme to plugin. For example- I enqueue a css in my theme using wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
Now, how I can call / enqueue the bootstrap inside my plugin from already registered in theme. I do not want to place bootstrap css file again in plugin's assets folder.
Hopefully, you got it.

Comment: But if your theme is already including it, then you’d just be adding it a second time.  If your theme isn’t properly enqueueing it then you have to address that first.

Comment: In my theme that is working. But, how I can enqueue inside plugin from theme css file?

Comment: I updated my answer.  But don't do it.

Comment: Isn't there any option to enqueue css/js from theme file to plugin using only handlers? For example- Already registered a css using "yourplugin-front" handler. Now How I can enqueue it inside plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in response to others, you want to *register* a stylesheet in your theme, and *enqueue* it from the plugin. In that case, you can call `wp_enqueue_script()` with just the handle you used with `wp_register_script()`, and no other arguments.

So in your theme, register the stylesheet.

```
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    function() {
        wp_register_style( 'my-stylesheet-handle', get_theme_file_uri( 'css/my-stylesheet.css' ) );
    }
);
```

Then in your plugin, you can enqueue the stylesheet like so:

```
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    function() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-stylesheet-handle' );
    },
    20
);
```

One thing you need to be aware of is that plugins load before themes, so when you hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` from the plugin, you should specify a priority greater than `10` so that it runs after the stylesheet has been registered by the theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_user_scripts() {
  $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style',  $plugin_url . "/css/style.css");
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'custom_user_scripts' );
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants something different from the comments on Tony's answer.